# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I get the error "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex" when I run the following code. The error occurs on this line and I think it is to do with the line.substring. The code runs smoothly when I take out line.Substring(11, 2) = "24" and run the code as  If line.StartsWith("123") Then currentRecord.ID = line.

I can't seem to get rid of the error.

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filePath)
If (line.StartsWith("123") And line.Substring(11, 2) = "24") Then currentRecord.ID = line
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how the error message doesn't speak for itself. What is the length of the string you're trying to get a substring from? What is the start index you're using to search from? Obviously the latter is not less than the former or you would be getting that error message. You obviously can't get a substring from past the end of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the line is long enough to access the substring at that position and length. AndAlso conditions will only trigger if the previous condition = true. If your version of VB.NET doesn't support AndAlso you will need to use nested ifs.

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filePath)
If (line.StartsWith("123") AndAlso Len(line)>=14 AndAlso line.Substring(11, 2) = "24") Then currentRecord.ID = line
```

Comment: You're welcome Martha. Good luck with your project.